# Random vector of two random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let's say I have two random variables: $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim E(1)$.

Is it meaningful to talk about the random vector $Z = (X,Y)$?

I ask because here we don't know it $X$ and $Y$ are defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$.

Are in this case $X$ and $Y$ independent variables?

Comment: If they are not defined on the same probability space, you cannot define the random vector because you do not know anything about the dependence between $X$ and $Y$. If they are independent, then you may define the vector, but if independence is not explicitly stated, I don't think you can assume it.

Comment: I think you're generally looking for the concept of a [product probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure). There's little reason to assume that your $X$ and $Y$ are defined over different probability spaces. Recall that a random variable maps from a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ to a measurable space $(E, \mathcal{E})$. In your case, the latter is the space of real numbers with the Borel sigma algebra and $P$ is defined **implicitly** via the CDF of $X$ and $Y$. Your $Z$ makes perfect sense, but you might not be able to compute its CDF (unless you have more info)

Comment: The only thing to add to these two fine comments is that speaking of $X$ as $Y$ as independent _requires_ them to be on the same probability space, since the definition of independent is that $$\underbrace{P[\{X\leq x\} \cap \{Y\leq y\}]} = P[X\leq x]P[Y\leq y] \quad  \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$$ and the probability in the underbrace would be undefined if $X$ and $Y$ are defined on different spaces.  PS: I am going to go out on a limb and say that, with high probability, you will **never**  need to define $X$ and $Y$ on different probability spaces if you are using them for the same problem.

Comment: Michael, but what about if X and Y are defined as above. I don't define the probability space, and I can't know which it is, or if they are different. Can I just assume (or should I) that they come from the same probability space, if they are part of the same problem?